# Change Windows 7/8 Wi-Fi Mac Address to custom value

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, spoofing

I am trying to change MAC address of Atheros AR9485 wireless card on Windows 8 and i am facing a limitation, that possible MAC addresses that can be set for Wi-Fi card in Windows 8 are:

```
X2-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX 
X6-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX 
XA-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX 
XE-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
```

But I want to set second number to different value.

Are there any way to do it?

Comment: One of the answers to the other question suggests thats not possible. In addition, the first two letters indicate the manufacturer and changing it wouldn't do much.

Comment: I need to change MAC address of this wireless card to MAC of another device to bypass our university's network limitations. So I have to change first two letters too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following software [Mac Address Changer](http://download.cnet.com/Technitium-MAC-Address-Changer/3000-2085_4-10554920.html)

Comment: According to [this program's blog](http://blog.technitium.com/2011/05/tmac-issue-with-wireless-network.html) it won't help to solve the problem, stated in my question.